# Accessing element in table (Selenium, C#)

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to automatize a task at work and this required i access an element inside a nested table. i managed to get the XPath through Chrome but getting an error that it cannot locate the element.

Error message:
[image]

Comment: Post the HTML of the desired element you want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use absolute xpath from chrome as this would likely to be failed. When you deal with tables the best practice is to accessing table>tr>td. Below is the example that would help you. This can be your starting point and then based on cell text you can click on the element.

```
//find table.
WebElement mytable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/table/tbody"));

//find rows of table.
List < WebElement > rows_table = mytable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

//calculate no of rows In table.
int rows_count = rows_table.size();

//Loop will execute for all the rows of the table
for (int row = 0; row < rows_count; row++) {

//find columns(cells) of that specific row.
List < WebElement > Columns_row = rows_table.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
//calculate no of columns(cells) In that specific row.
int columns_count = Columns_row.size();
System.out.println("Number of cells In Row " + row + " are " + columns_count);

//Loop will execute till the last cell of that specific row.
for (int column = 0; column < columns_count; column++) {
    //To retrieve text from the cells.
    String celltext = Columns_row.get(column).getText();
    System.out.println("Cell Value Of row number " + row + " and column number " + column + " Is " + celltext);
}
}
```

Comment: This one solved it, thank you for the assistance :)